# Running a regression

Tags: r, dataframe

Background: my data set has 52 rows and 12 columns (assume column names are `A` - `L`) and the name of my data set is `foo`

I am told to run a regression where `foo$L` is the dependent variable, and all other variables are independent except for `foo$K`.

The way i was doing it is

```
fit <- lm(foo$L ~ foo$a + ... +foo$J)
```

then calling

```
summary(fit)
```

Is my way a good way to run a regression and finding the intercept and coef?

Comment: You should [make your example reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example). That said, you shouldn't subset within formula notation—use the `data` parameter, it's done automatically: `lm(mpg ~ wt + hp, mtcars)`

Comment: Agreeing with @alistaire  but using your example you should use something like `lm(K ~ ., data=foo[,-11])`

Comment: i see so it would be more efficient to use data parameter

Answer (score 3):

Use the `data` argument to `lm` so you don't have to use the `foo$` syntax for each predictor. Use `dependent ~ .` as the formula to have the dependent variable predicted by all other variables. Then you can use `- K` to exclude `K`:

```
data_mat = matrix(rnorm(52 * 12), nrow = 52)

df = as.data.frame(data_mat)
colnames(df) = LETTERS[1:12]

lm(L ~ . - K, data = df)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first remove the column `K`, and then do `fit <- lm(L ~ ., data = foo)`. This will treat the `L` column as the dependent variable and all the other columns as the independent variables. You don't have to specify each column names in the formula.

Here is an example using the `mtcars`, fitting a multiple regression model to `mpg` with all the other variables except `carb`.

```
mtcars2 <- mtcars[, !names(mtcars) %in% "carb"]

fit <- lm(mpg ~ ., data = mtcars2)

summary(fit)

# Call:
#   lm(formula = mpg ~ ., data = mtcars2)
# 
# Residuals:
#   Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
# -3.3038 -1.6964 -0.1796  1.1802  4.7245 
# 
# Coefficients:
#   Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)   
# (Intercept) 12.83084   18.18671   0.706  0.48790   
# cyl         -0.16881    0.99544  -0.170  0.86689   
# disp         0.01623    0.01290   1.259  0.22137   
# hp          -0.02424    0.01811  -1.339  0.19428   
# drat         0.70590    1.56553   0.451  0.65647   
# wt          -4.03214    1.33252  -3.026  0.00621 **
# qsec         0.86829    0.68874   1.261  0.22063   
# vs           0.36470    2.05009   0.178  0.86043   
# am           2.55093    2.00826   1.270  0.21728   
# gear         0.50294    1.32287   0.380  0.70745   
# ---
#   Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
# 
# Residual standard error: 2.593 on 22 degrees of freedom
# Multiple R-squared:  0.8687,  Adjusted R-squared:  0.8149 
# F-statistic: 16.17 on 9 and 22 DF,  p-value: 9.244e-08
```